# Z-index Organization Strategy

Tags: css, sass

What is a good organizational strategy for dealing with z-indices on a web page?

I am developing a single page app that has many layers due to things like error messages, loading gifs, and modal boxes, and I keep finding myself with elements on top of each other when it doesn't make any visual sense.

Is there a generally accepted approach to how to organize z-indices of various elements?  I have searched google and SO but haven't seen any that seem general enough.

I am using SASS in my project so I can easily do addition based on a base z-index, but a general CSS strategy would be even better.

Comment: simple, don't specify it until you need to...

Comment: Remember greater z-index does not always mean rendered above

Comment: Xander is right, if you're laying out your page properly you'll only need to use z-index in rare cases anyway. Keep them to the absolute minimum is the ideal strategy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally prefer to specify a large z-index for my top-level elements.  The best approach I've found is to begin by

- determine what elements **must** be on top of other elements
- since you are using SASS, you could specify a few variables for various z-index levels:

  .tierBottom
  {
  position:[whatever you need];
  z-index: 1;
  }

  .tierMiddle
  {
  position:[whatever you need];
  z-index: 100;
  }

  .tierTop{
  position:[whatever you need];
  z-index: 1000;
  }
- As a few others have stated, you shouldn't have to worry about most of the containers/wrappers z-index.  In the event that you hit some issues, like content being on top, add the low-tier z-index class to the offending element and all should be right with the world.

There may be a lot of different opinions on this, and it may not be the best practice for some, but this is what has worked for me in the past.  Hope it helps!